# making each animation start with different frame

Tags: objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am animating the same sprite five times at different positions. I would like each sprite to begin it's animation from the second frame of the previous one. How can I do this? Below is a sample of my code.

```
NSMutableArray *frameArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++) 
{
 [frameArray addObject:
 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"groupSprite%d.png", i]]];    } 

//Starting the Animation
CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frameArray delay: 0.2];
groupSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:groupSprite1.png];
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            groupSprite.position = posArray[i];
            id action =[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation :animation]];
            [groupSprite runAction:action];
            [self addChild: groupSprite];

            [groupSpriteArray addObject:groupSprite];


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented exactly what you need some time ago. Here is the pull-request:

- https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/pull/249

I am not sure if they finally ended up merging it or not.